# How to call getServerSideprops with useEffect in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am building a project using next.js but I have an issue that getServerSideProps is called 6 times when the page is rendered.

Here is the code at the top in pages.

```
const NewFindstay: React.FC<INewFindstayProps> = ({ findstayList }) => {
  const [isMap, setIsMap] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div id="contents">
      <FindstayFilter setIsMap={setIsMap} isMap={isMap} />
      <FindstayList findstayList={findstayList} isMap={isMap} />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps({ query, req }) {
  let findstayList = null;
  try {
    findstayList = await getPlaceListAsync(
      { ...query },
      req.headers.cookie ? req.headers.cookie : null
    );
  } catch (e) {
    findstayList = null;
  }
  return {
    props: {
      findstayList,
      query,
    },
  };
}

export default NewFindstay;
```

Seems this is caused by components that imported inside of FindstayFilter. (let's say components A, B, C, D, E, F)

Each components of A, B, C, D, E, F has useEffect hook for setState.

```
// A
 useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query.city) {
      setSelectedCity(router.query.city);
    };
  }, [router.query.city]);

// B
  useEffect(() => {
    setDateRange({
      startDate: check_in ? moment(check_in) : null,
      endDate: check_out ? moment(check_out) : null
    })
  }, [router.query.check_in, router.query.check_out]);
// C
  useEffect(() => {
    const queryPrice = {
      min: price_min ? (parseInt(price_min as string, 10) / 10000) : 0,
      max: price_max ? (parseInt(price_max as string, 10) / 10000) : 100
    }
    setRangePrice(queryPrice);
  }, [router.query.price_min, router.query.price_max]);

// D, E, F use same pattern as well.
```

In order words, when FindstayFilter component renders, useEffect hook inside A, B, C, D, E, F rerender the component total 6 times which triggers calling getServerSideProps 6 times as well.

How can I minimize calling getServerSideProps? should I use useEffect hook only inside of FindstayFilter component and crammed many setstate code into the hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was wrong.

I put useEffect hook with dependency array state inside in every component so that whenever states changes, **router.push** works.

```
  const pushRouter = (renderQuery) => {
    return (
      router.push({
        pathname: "/findstay",
        query: {
          ...router.query,
          ...renderQuery,
          page: 1,
          per: 10
        }
      })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const queryCnt = {
      adultCnt: adult_cnt ? parseInt(adult_cnt as string, 10) : 0,
      childCnt: child_cnt ? parseInt(child_cnt as string, 10) : 0,
      babyCnt: baby_cnt ? parseInt(baby_cnt as string, 10) : 0
    };
    pushRouter(queryCnt)
  }, [adult_cnt, child_cnt, baby_cnt]);
```

However router.push works as ssr in my code(it is supposed to work as csr) which means when **FindstayFilter** renders, pushRouter function in children components A, B, C, D, E, F also works and this leads to getServerSideProps renders 6 times.

Now I have to find a reason why router.push works ssr
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9586

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideProps` is only called when the page first loads because it will call the nodejs server of nextjs. That will be always the case no mater what, unless you do some reloading/refreshing the page.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering